# Int value inside array cell somehow being stored as a separate 2d array address

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct, malloc, field

I've created this struct, and a function that initializes all of the fields within that struct and returns a struct pointer. Within this struct I have one single dimensional array of integers, and a two dimensional array of pointers. However, when initialing and incrementing the value inside the cells inside party->fragment_sizes[I] (single dimensional array), party->fragment_sizes[] also begins to increment (two dimensional array). Party->fragment_sizes[i] goes from NULL (0x0) to (0x10000), (0x2000000) I have no idea how, but it's messing me up pretty badly. I need party_fragments_sizes to remain NULL until allocated (inside another function).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LonelyPartyArray
{
    int **fragments;      // the address of fragments[i] is being set as
    int *fragment_sizes;  // the value inside fragment_sizes[i]
} LonelyPartyArray;

LonelyPartyArray *createParty(int num_fragments)
{
    int i;

    // Allocating LonelyPartyArray struct pointer
    LonelyPartyArray *party = malloc(sizeof(LonelyPartyArray));

    // I am allocating these separately, 
    // is something going on with how my system is
    // allocating space for these arrays?

    // Allocating LonelyPartyArray
    party->fragments = malloc(sizeof(int *) * num_fragments);

    // Allocating LonelyPartyArray fragment size
    party->fragment_sizes = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_fragments);

    // Initializing party->fragments to NULL (not used) and fragment_sizes to zero
    for (i = 0; i < num_fragments; i++)
        party->fragments[i] = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < num_fragments; i++)
        party->fragment_sizes[i] = 0;

    // Party->fragments[I] is not remaining NULL, but is being
    // incremented. (I.e., party-fragments[I] increments 0x0, 
    // 0x10000, 0x20000, 0x30000 etc). This needs to remain NULL.
    for (i = 0; i < num_fragments; i++)
    {
        if (party->fragments[i] != party->fragment_sizes[i])
            break;
        printf("Why is this happening???? [%d]\n", i);
        printf("%p\n, party->fragments[i]);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    LonelyPartyArray *party = createParty(3);

    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea how party->fragments[] is being set as the address for party->fragment_sizes[], but I need them to be separate.

Comment: What makes you think `party->fragments[i]` is being set as the address of `party->fragment_sizes[i]`? You're not getting the address of `party->fragment_sizes[i]`, you're getting its value.

Comment: Use `if (party->fragments[i] != &party->fragment_sizes[i])`

Comment: When party->fragments[] is incremented, the address of party->fragment_sizes[] is incremented. The party->fragment_sizes[] address goes from NULL (0x0) to 0x100000, 0x200000, 0x300000, etc. Party->fragment_sizes[] needs to remain NULL @Barmar

Comment: `fragment_sizes` contains integers, not pointers, why are you comparing with pointers?

Comment: Because the pointer (party->fragments[I]) is changing from NULL to the value of the integer. I meant to say the party->fragments[I] address increments in my last comment. Sorry

Comment: I fixed the missing quote in`printf("%p\n, party->fragments[i]);` and ran your program. It prints `0x0` each time through the loop.